# Is the connection over Tor between client and remote node safe?

Tags: privacy, cryptography, tor, encryption, attack

I'm using torsocks to connect my CLI wallet to a remote node (geo.node.moneroworld.com:18089). I don't need a high level of anonymity, but I would like to understand what information is at risk. For example, can a malicious hacker sniff my wallet password?

Answer (score 1):

Your wallet password is local to the wallet. It's not sent to the daemon, which never gets hold of that, nor the wallet keys. Using Tor, information is encrypted between your own tor daemon (though if you're going to use a third party Monero daemon, you might be using a third party Tor daemon, which is even worse) and the destination hidden service, so any snooper in the middle is not going to see anything unencrypted.

Comment: And without Tor what information can the remote node see?

Comment: The exact same as with Tor, since Tor encrypts between your starting point and the hidden service. That'll include your current height, any tx you send, your owned outputs should you run commands like rescan_spent, etc. No keys or anything like that. If you run with --untrusted-daemon, the RPC will configure their parameters to disclose less, at the price of more work.